# getClass.getResourceAsStream sometimes (not always) returns null in ScalaTests

Tags: scala, sbt, scalatest

I created my own ScalaTest spec. This mixes in `FlatSpecLike` and defines a method `putResource` so I can put a file from `src/test/resources` into some directory.

Basically, the method uses something like

```
val ins = getClass.getResourceAsStream(resourceName)
```

and uses some copying with `Channel`s.

Now, in my test, I extend this spec, mixin `BeforeAndAfterAll` and in my `beforeAll` method, I do something like:

```
val tempDir = Files.createTempDirectory("temp-directory-").toFile
putResource("/foo.bar", new File(tempDir, "foo.bar"))
```

Sometimes, when running it from the command line via `sbt test` or from Jenkins, the `getClass.getResourceAsStream` is `null`, so the test fails. However, when running the exact same for a second time, it works.

What is wrong here?

Comment: Just to clarify: you copy an existing file _from_ resources to somewhere else, right? Because if you write _to_ resources, you have to create the file before you refer to it as a resource.

Comment: Yes, I have the files in `src/test/resources`, and try yo get them via `getClass.getResourceAsStream`. In about 10% of all test runs with `sbt test`, the stream I get is `null`.